# Change displayed url without redirecting to another page

Tags: javascript, php, html, web

Is it possible to change the whole URL without changing the page?

For example:

I have a website named `www.abcdef.com/index.php` and I want to display `www.xyz.com/index1.php` in the browser.

Maybe you can help me out haha.

Thanks :D

Comment: You should read about htaccess

Comment: no it's not - because of phishing... what is the usecase?

Comment: while you can change the url (regardless filepath of the file on server) displayed on client side, you can't change the domain name for a specific page/location.